# How to prevent player movement in VB.NET for a platformer game?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a platformer game and on either side of my map I have two invisible walls. When the player's picture box comes in contact with these walls I want it to stop moving so that the player cannot move outside the bounds of the map. Is there any simple way to stop prevent the movement of a picture box? I will paste my code down below in case anyone wants it or if you need it to see what Im trying to do.

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim clsnBoxes(1) As PictureBox

    Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        'allows for left/right movement
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Right
                tmrRight.Enabled = True
                tmrLeft.Enabled = False
                clsnTmr.Enabled = True
            Case Keys.Left
                tmrRight.Enabled = False
                tmrLeft.Enabled = True
                clsnTmr.Enabled = True
        End Select


    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp

        'stops movement after key has been released
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Right
                tmrRight.Enabled = False
            Case Keys.Left
                tmrLeft.Enabled = False
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'stops manual scrolling
        Me.AutoScroll = False

        clsnBoxes(0) = Me.clsnBx1
        clsnBoxes(1) = Me.clsnBx2

    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrLeft_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrLeft.Tick

        'moves all of the clouds left 
        Dim Objects() As PictureBox = {pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, clsnBx1, clsnBx2}
        For x = 0 To Objects.Length - 1
            Objects(x).Left += 3
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrRight_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrRight.Tick

        'moves all of the clouds right
        Dim Objects() As PictureBox = {pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, clsnBx1, clsnBx2}
        For x = 0 To Objects.Length - 1
            Objects(x).Left -= 3
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub clsnTmr_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles clsnTmr.Tick
        For index = 0 To 1
            If Me.picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(clsnBoxes(index).Bounds) Then

            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some more details: what have you already tried, and what problem are you currently facing? Please see also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have left and right reversed for some mysterious reason.  Just prevent an object from moving too far: Objects(x).Left = Math.Max(LeftWallPosition, Objects(x).Left - 3).

Answer (score 0):

I'll take in example just one movement, it's the same for the others. Just add a test before doing the movement

```
Private Sub tmrLeft_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrLeft.Tick

        'Assuming that pic1 is the most left pictures of all
        'Assuming that MINIMUM_LEFT is the position of the wall + its width
        If pic1.Left <= MINIMUM_LEFT Then Exit Sub 

        [...your movement code...]

    End Sub
```